# SQL schema design question around relating 2 different types of ID's to one piece of information

Tags: mysql, sql, schema

I'm working on redesigning some parts of our schema, and I'm running into a problem where I just don't know a good clean way of doing something.  I have an event table such as:

```
Events
--------
event_id
```

for each event, there could be n groups or users associated with it.  So there's a table relating Events to Users to reflect that one to many relationship such as:

```
EventUsers
----------
event_id
user_id
```

The problem is that we also have a concept of groups.  We want to potentially tie n groups to an event in addition to users.  So, that user_id column isn't sufficient, because we need to store potentially either a user_id or a group_id.

I've thought of a variety of ways to handle this, but they all seem like a big hack.  For example, I could make that a participant_id and put in a participant_type column such as:

```
EventUsers
----------
event_id
participant_id
participant_type
```

and if I wanted to get the events that user_id 10 was a part of, it could be something like:

```
select event_id
from EventUsers 
where participant_id = 10 
and participant_type = 1
```

(assuming that somewhere participant_type 1 was defined to be a User).  But I don't like that from a philosophical point of view because when I look at the data, I don't know what the number in participant_id means unless I also look at the value in particpant_type.

I could also change EventUsers to be something like:

```
EventParticipants
-----------------
event_id
user_id
group_id
```

and allow the values of user_id and group_id to be NULL if that record is dealing with the other type of information.

Of course, I could just break EventUsers and we'll call it EventGroups into 2 different tables but I'd like to keep who is tied to an event stored in one single place if there's a good logical way to do it.

So, am I overlooking a good way to accomplish this?

Comment: You could have an "EventGroups" table for `event_id, group_id`. A single user could be in a group that contains only that user. At least that feels a bit cleaner in some ways.

Answer (score 4):

Tables Events, Users and Groups represent the basic entities.  They are related by EventUsers, GroupUsers and EventGroups.  You need to union results together, e.g. the attendees for an event are:

```
select user_id
  from EventUsers
  where event_id = @event_id
union
select GU.user_id
  from EventGroups as EG inner join
    GroupUsers as GU on GU.group_id = EG.group_id
  where EG.event_id = @event_id
```

Don't be shy about creating additional tables to represent different types of things.  It is often easier to combine them, e.g. with union, than to try to sort out a mess of vague data.

Comment: I was going to add a similar query to my answer but saw something shiny and got distracted. +1 for going to the effort of explaining it nicely

Comment: Ok, after further thought, you (and Phil) are probably right.  Let me throw another wrinkle in here though.  Each Event also has two types of activities, Lectures and Meetings.  So, we'd need an EventLectures and EventMeetings to track which lectures and meetings are part of an Event.  That's fine.  But, we also need to track information about what happened to each user and group at each lecture and meeting they attened.  So now we need an EventUserMeeting, EventUserLecture, EventGroupMeeting, EventGroupLecture if we follow this paradigm, right?

Comment: I'm concerned about too many tables requiring too many unions and joins because I'm worried about my abililty to retrieve all the data for an Event quickly.

Comment: How complex can an event be?  Might is consist of two lectures followed by a meeting?  Tables: Events, Lectures, Meetings.  Relate them with EventLectures and EventMeetings, perhaps using a date/time to rank the activities within an event.  Tables are cheap and it is still easier to combine disparate data than to separate a bag of entities.  In the SQL Server world I have used views and user defined functions to bury the details.

Comment: @John Also, you won't need the EventUsers and EventGroups tables if the relationship between users/groups is made with lectures/meetings. You can determine the event by tracing it back from the lecture/meeting.

Answer (score 3):

> Of course, I could just break EventUsers and we'll call it EventGroups into 2 different tables

This is the *good logical way to do it*. Create a [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) for each *many-to-many* relationship; one for events and users, the other for events and groups.

Answer (score 1):

There's no correct answer to this question (although I'm sure if you look hard enough you'll finds some purists that believe that their approach is the correct one).

Personally, I'm a fan of the second approach because it allows you to give columns names that accurately reflect the data they contain. This makes your `SELECT` statements (in particular when it comes to joining) a bit easier to understand. Yeah, you'll end up with a bunch of `NULL` values in the column that is unused, but that's not really a big deal.

However, if you'll be joining on this table a lot, it might be wise to go with the first approach, so that the column you join on is consistently the same. Also, if you anticipate new types of `participant` being added in the future, which would result in a third column in `EventParticipants`, then you might want to go with the first approach to keep the table narrow.